# jXLS 2.3 - add the listener to update a cell style depending on the cell content?

Tags: excel, jxls

There is an [example](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/samples/dynamicstylesample.html) of the dynamic cell styling for jXLS 1.x, but I can not find anything closer than [this example](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/area_listener.html) for AreaListener.

I have a very basic template for the XLS generation, and the processing code as simple as

```
context.putVar("headers", columns);
context.putVar("data", cells);
context.getConfig().setCellStyleMap();
JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, result, context);
```

How can I add some listener that will allow me to modify the style for certain cells (like add the word-wrap for the text longer than N character, or change the background color if the value is of certain pattern)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43813394/548473 answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

In the main method:

```
        try(InputStream is = HighlightDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("highlight_template.xls")) {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("target/highlight_output.xls")) {
            PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is, os);
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer, false);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area mainArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            Area loopArea = xlsAreaList.get(0).getCommandDataList().get(0).getCommand().getAreaList().get(0);
            loopArea.addAreaListener(new HighlightCellAreaListener(transformer));
            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("employees", employees);
            mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
            mainArea.processFormulas();
            transformer.write();
        }
    }
```

The template used in this example is the same as in [Object Collection Demo](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/object_collection.html) sample. The trickiest part is to find the area where do you want to apply the AreaListener. In this case I just traversed from the root area to the EachCommand area where I wish to highlight employees with payment over 2000.

The AreaListener implementation is similar to the one in [AreaListener example](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/area_listener.html)

```
public class HighlightCellAreaListener implements AreaListener {
    private final CellRef paymentCell = new CellRef("Template!C4")
 ...
    public void afterTransformCell(CellRef srcCell, CellRef targetCell, Context context) {
    System.out.println("Source: " + srcCell.getCellName() + ", Target: " + targetCell.getCellName());
    if(paymentCell.equals(srcCell)){ // we are at employee payment cell
        Employee employee = (Employee) context.getVar("employee");
        if( employee.getPayment().doubleValue() > 2000 ){ // highlight payment when >= $2000
            logger.info("highlighting payment for employee " + employee.getName());
            highlightCell(targetCell);
            }
        }
    }
private void highlightCell(CellRef cellRef) {
    Workbook workbook = transformer.getWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(cellRef.getSheetName());
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(cellRef.getRow()).getCell(cellRef.getCol());
    CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
    CellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    newCellStyle.setDataFormat( cellStyle.getDataFormat() );
    newCellStyle.setFont( workbook.getFontAt( cellStyle.getFontIndex() ));
    newCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor( cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor());
    newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
    newCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible implementation with using redefined `JxlsHelper`:

```
JxlsHelper jxlsHelper = JxlsHelper.getInstance();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(templateFile); OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    PoiTransformer transformer = createTransformer(is, os);
    Context context = new Context();
    ctx.putVar(...);
    jxlsHelper.setAreaBuilder(new XlsCommentAreaBuilder() {
        @Override
        public List<Area> build() {
            List<Area> areas = super.build();
            Area targetArea = xlsAreaList.get(0).getCommandDataList().get(0).
                     getCommand().getAreaList().get(0);  // find targetArea in debug
            targetArea.addAreaListener(
                     new HighlightCellAreaListener(transformer.getWorkbook()));
            return areas;
        }
    });
    jxlsHelper.processTemplate(context, transformer);
}
```