# JXLS: Colorize a line dependent on the expressions content

Tags: jxls

I'm a beginner with JXLS. I read the [Documentation for formulas](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/formulas.html) but am stuck.

Let's take their example with the employees:
[image]

I want to colorize the entire row in green, when an employee is earns more than 2000 Dollars (column "payment", variable "employee.payment").

In the documentations example:
[image]

I would want to have row 5, 6 and 8 colorized in green.

Is this possible? If yes, how? Using the comment commands? Or do I need java code? I don't have code to show as it is quite big and not from me, so I'm not perfectly familiar with it. So for the sake of the issue, we can look at the documentaries code. Mine is similar to that.

```
Area xlsArea;
Context context;
// construct XLS Area and set it into xlsArea var
// ...
// fill in context var with data
// ...
// apply XLS Area at A1 cell of 'Result' sheet
xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
// process area formulas
xlsArea.processFormulas();
// save excel output
// ...
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Leonids suggestion using the if-else construct, I now got this working by putting an extra "cheat line" underneath, which has the desired color:

[image]

but I am facing one problem now: looking at the employees example, I could have 10 of them, but also 1000 - I simply don't know, the data comes dynamically. So then this happens:

[image]

My "cheat line" appears at line 23. That's a problem .......
As I could have 1 million employees, I can't put it just far enough underneath, that line could always appear in the result when having too much data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways how you can achieve row highlighting in Jxls-2.

One is to use [if-command](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/if_command.html) and another one is to use [AreaListener](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/area_listener.html).

You can find an example of using [if-command](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/if_command.html) for row highlighting in [EachIfCommandDemo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/c5ae177fae1480be45d115045d5d4615a8637f4d/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/EachIfCommandDemo.java?at=master) in [jxls-demo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/) project.

You can find an example of using [AreaListener](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/area_listener.html) for cell highlighting in [AreaListenerDemo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/c5ae177fae1480be45d115045d5d4615a8637f4d/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/AreaListenerDemo.java?at=master).

Comment: Digging into that if-else construct, do I understand correctly that I simply duplicate my logic, but on one line default, on the other line with color? Isn't this a bit messy regarding maintenance of the code? Changing would mean double work, error prone etc.? Nevertheless I'll give it a try, thanks so far

Comment: You can generate the output to another sheet and remove the original sheet. Alternatively you can try to pass the second parameter to XlsCommentAreaBuilder constructor to clean the template cells before generating the output.

Comment: Removing the sheet works. But I now realize, that with that IF-ELSE mechanism, my other comments won't get interpreted anymore. You can even see this in my last screenshot, the lines on top show the red comment triangle, while the other lines don't. If I remove this IF-ELSE, everything works again. Do you have an idea why this might happen? The comments are interpreted by an area listener, which then formats the cells (in this case for price formatting)

Comment: My formatting and then using `cell.removeCellComment();` gets executed in debugger, but seems to do nothing as the result shows. But it works on the "not by if statement affected rows", so it really still works, but not for the if-else area .....

Comment: Nevermind, I got now everything like I want, although it is quite hacky here and there ... not pretty, but whatever .. thanks

Comment: Area Listener Example docs: https://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/area_listener.html

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to cross Excel markup with custom listener by workaround:

```
JxlsHelper jxlsHelper = JxlsHelper.getInstance();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(templateFile); OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    PoiTransformer transformer = createTransformer(is, os);
    Context context = new Context();
    ctx.putVar(...);
    jxlsHelper.setAreaBuilder(new XlsCommentAreaBuilder() {
        @Override
        public List<Area> build() {
            List<Area> areas = super.build();
            Area coloredArea = areas.get(0).getCommandDataList().get(0).getCommand()  // users EachCommand
                    .getAreaList().get(0).getCommandDataList().get(1).getCommand() // meals EachCommand
                    .getAreaList().get(0);  // find colored area in debug
            coloredArea.addAreaListener(new ColorAreaListener(transformer.getWorkbook()));
            return areas;
        }
    });
    jxlsHelper.processTemplate(context, transformer);
}
```

In `ColorAreaListener` I do not clone `CellStyle`s, but get it form the template's cells outside processing area.
Of cause after add to template new command you need to change code for defining `coloredArea`.